# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts in c# windows form

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I want to connect my windows form application to mysql .It works local mysql server perfectly.But it didn't work in online mysql.

My code is

```
string mysqlconnection = "Server=mysql.main-hosting.com;Database=xxxxxxxxx;Uid=yyyyyyy;Password=zzzzzzzz;";
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(mysqlconnection);
connection.Open();
```

It shows **Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.**.How to solve this?

Comment: Can you connect with Workbench to this server using the same URL, username and password?

Comment: no ,What is workbench?

Comment: http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ It's a (the "official") gui-tool with which you are able to access/develop/drop or view mysql-databases. If you are not able to connect with Workbench either, you will have to configure your firewall to allow your connection

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Server=mysql.main-hosting.com;Database=xxxxxxxxx;User ID=yyyyyyy;Password=zzzzzzzz;
```

Instead of

```
Server=mysql.main-hosting.com;Database=xxxxxxxxx;Uid=yyyyyyy;Password=zzzzzzzz;
```

Maybe it is a connectionstring problem.

Or otherwise the server address is wrong.

Comment: I think it's more of a firewall problem

Comment: can't mysql.main-hosting.com reach also, so I think the address is wrong. Indeed maybe a firewal, but i guess the server address needs to be more specific.

Comment: Or he did not write the right address to SO, because of security concerns